# Javascript apply different styles to same element based on media query

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

With javascript, is it possible to change the style of a element separately within CSS media-queries?

In particular we have a hero image that uses two different images depending on screen size.  We are writing a page load script that loads the visible content of the next page without changing the static part of the webpage.  With the next page load, we want to change both the values with new images every time we load new page contents.

```
// code when page initially loaded    
#splash {
  background-image: url("1st-phone-img.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  #splash {
    background-image: url("1st-fullsize-img.jpg");
  }
}
```

.

```
// when page 2 content loaded, need to change css to use two new images
#splash {
  background-image: url("2nd-phone-img.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  #splash {
    background-image: url("2nd-fullsize-img.jpg");
  }
}
```

I know I can do a basic targeting via `document.getElementById('splash').style.backgroundImage = "url(2nd-phone-img.jpg)';` , but is there a way target the 501px + value with a different image?

Or do I need to target everything inside the `<style></style>` tags for text replacement (if that is even possible)?

**--- Edit with more info ---**

My apologies but I am not a coder, just someone who maintains one website for my small business and have obviously not explained my question clearly.

I believe one term for what we are doing is page hydration.  We are loading a static html page and then rather than reloading the next page in its entirety, we are using javascript to fetch just the content that changes and replace it, while leaving the framework, footer, navigation, etc from the first page loaded.

One change that occurs is the hero image, which as shown above uses two different images depending on device.  I need both CSS background-images to change, as some devices cross over, vertical they use the phone image, horizontal they use the full image.

**- - - One More Try to Explain - - -**

I have a div that uses two different background images, determined via CSS based on device width.  With vanilla javascript and after the page has loaded, I want to be able to change BOTH background-image url values.  Using `style.backgroundImage` only changes the image currently visible, not the alternate to be used when the visitor changes their tablet's orientation.

Comment: Quite unclear what you ask... Are you willing to change for instance `"fullsize-img.jpg"` to `"fullsize-alternative-img.jpg"`? If so, what browser support do you need? For newest browsers css variables are the way to go, but if you need IE, then it might be harder.

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4mqde91/2/), it shows you how to use CSS variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different images based on screen size, then media queries are the way to go.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)
    #splash {
      background-image: url("phone-img.jpg");
    }
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  #splash {
    background-image: url("fullsize-img.jpg");
  }
}
```

If you want to do this from code you can use the resize event handler.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () =? {
  if(window.innerWidth < 501) {
    document.querySelector('#spash').style.backgroundImage = 'url("phone-img.jpg")';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#spash').style.backgroundImage = 'url("fullsize-img.jpg")';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [window.resize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cross-browser-window-resize-event-using-javascript-jquery/) method

```
function getWindowSize() {
    var inner_width = window.innerWidth;
}

window.onresize = getWindowSize;

if(inner_width >= 501){
   document.getElementById('spash').style.backgroundImage: url("fullsize-img.jpg");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you want to change the image with the window size using CSS media-queries, then the code you have written is correct, but instead of setting a min-width, **change it to max-width**, so if the window width is less then '501px' then in media queries set this image as background-image URL "phone-img.jpg" and if the window width is greater then '501px' then set this outside the media-query as a background-image URL "fullsize-img.jpg". Here's id the sample of your code.

```
#splash {
  background-image: url("fullsize-img.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 501px) {
  #splash {
    background-image: url("phone-img.jpg");
  }
}
```

But one important thing is, you need to give height and width to the tag you are using the background image for and background-image URL don't work with a span tag, div tag is recommended

```
<div id="splash" style="height:500px; width: 500px"></div>
```